# How to call a function when select an option in angular material dropbox?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, angular-material

When I use angular material mat-select, I want to call a function to console log the name of the selected item. But why the console log the current one and the previous one?
These are my code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 1rem; width: 100px;">
    <mat-label>Groups</mat-label>
         <mat-select>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let name of groupNames" [value]="name 
                 (onSelectionChange)="getActivitiesInGroup(name)">
                    {{ name }}
              </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
groupNames = ['A','D','T','C']
getActivitiesInGroup(name: string): void {
        console.log(name);
}
```

So I first select 'A' and the condole log 'A', after that I select 'T', why console first log 'T' and then log 'A'? How can I let console just log 'T' during the second selection?

Answer (score 3):

Which Angular version you are using?

**Angular 6+:**

You should use the `selectionChange` event on `mat-select` rather than `mat-option`:

```
<mat-select name="countryString" [(value)]="selectedCountry" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange(selectedCountry)"
  placeholder="Country">
  <mat-option [value]="'GB'">Great Britain</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="'US'">United States</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="'CA'">Canada</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Demo on stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-vqnv8h?file=src/app/app.component.html